# what could prevent keydown events from being fired in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keydown, textinput

I've made an editable implementation which behaviour is:

dblclick on element makes it editable:

- an input is created
- element contents emptied
- input appended to element
- attach keydown event handler to input, to disable edition when user presses Enter
- idem with blur event

It works fine in decents browsers, but it breaks on IE8.

there are two problems:

- `input.focus()` will call the blur event handler (wtf??)
- keystrokes won't generate events intercepted by keydown handler, so my handler to validate when enter is hit don't work
- I checked clicks events on the input and they are fine

The thing is it still works if I run the sample in a minimalist sample, but in my application, it won't.

**what could prevent those keydown events from being fired / catch ?**

here's the implementation:

```
widget.Editable = function( el, options ) {
    this.element = $(el).addClass('editable');
    this.value = this.element.text();

    var _that = this;
    this.element.dblclick( function(e) {
        _that.enableEdition();
    } );
};

widget.Editable.prototype = {
    disableEdition: function( save, e ) {
        this.value = this.input.val();
        this.input.remove();
        this.element.text( this.value ).removeClass('dragDisable');
        this.editionEnabled = false;
        this.onupdate( e, this.value, this.element );
    },
    /**
     * enables the field for edition. Its contents will be placed in an input. Then
     * a hit on "enter" key will save the field.
     * @method enableEdition
     */
    enableEdition: function() {
        if (this.editionEnabled) return;
        var _that = this;
        this.value = this.element.text();
        this.input = $( document.createElement('input') ).attr({
            type:'text',
            value:this.value
        });
        this.element
            .empty().append( this.input )
            .addClass('dragDisable'); //We must disable drag in order to not prevent selection
        this.input.keydown( function(e) {
            IScope.log('keydown editable:', e );
            switch ( e.keyCode ) {
            case 13:
                _that.disableEdition( true );
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } );
        this.input.click( function() {
            console.log('input clicked');
        });

        //if ( !YAHOO.env.ua.ie ) 
        //  this.input.blur( function( e ) {
        //      IScope.log( "editable blurred", e );
        //      _that.disableEdition( true );
        //  });

        //this.input.focus();
        this.editionEnabled = true;
    }
};
```